# How to make a List<> that holds voids?

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, void

I get an error when I do `List<void> voidList = new List<void>();`.
How would I do something like that, that holds voids?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: What possible application would this have? Or are you wanting to hold functions that return `void`?

Comment: Consider making the title more reflective of the actual goal(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works on Mono:

```
var x = new List<System.Void>();
```

Of course,

```
var x = new List<Action>();
```

works equally well, but is way more useful

Comment: @sq33G the closest reference I found within the language spec is [typeof(void) 7.5.11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691348(v=vs.71).aspx); see also Mono Bug report [typeof(System.Void) is not allowed](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2003-May/005020.html). I'd say: bug

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking to hold a list of void methods, you could use `List<Action>`.

Comment: ...as long as the methods take no parameters

Answer (score 0):

Why?

You can Create a List which will allow any object (or boxed struct) into the list.

But you are basically using a generic list for something that isn't generic.  You can create the most common base class to store your objects in.  If there is no common, then Object is what you are after.

Comment: After your update I'd agree with @Sam Pearson, you actually want a list of void delegates.  In C# 4 the right way is to use Action

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DoStuff1() { ... }
private void DoStuff2() { ... }

var myActions = new List<Action> { DoStuff1, DoStuff2 };
```

Then, say, you might want to loop through and invoke them all:

```
foreach (var action in myActions)
{
    action();
}
```

Comment: This gives a compile-time error:

`CS1950 The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments` and `CS1921 The best overloaded method match for 'EditUserUC.ResetName()' has wrong signature for the initializer element. The initializable Add must be an accessible instance method.`